# Use an array to store numbers and dates, then match and extract them from the array?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, foreach, simplexml

I have a form where a user enters 6 numbers. I've used a SimpleXML foreach loop to compare the entered numbers to the numbers in the xml file. I want to check if any 3 entered numbers match any 3 within an xml element, then display the date and match number associated with the element. I have it working if all 6 numbers match but trying to make it work if any 3 numbers match.

How do I use an array to get numbers and dates from the xml file and then extract and match against numbers entered on the form?

The code is what I have so far but doesn't use an array. It only compares 6 entered numbers against 6 in the xml file. I want to be able to use an array to collect the numbers and extract then compare.

XML (minified here)

```
<lottery>
<number>
    <date>7.11.2015</date>
    <num1>2</num1>
    <num2>3</num2>
    <num3>34</num3>
    <num4>43</num4>
    <num5>49</num5>
    <num6>50</num6>
    <match>10</match>
    <jackpot>13156375</jackpot>
</number>
<number>
    <date>08.11.2015</date>
    <num1>11</num1>
    <num2>13</num2>
    <num3>18</num3>
    <num4>25</num4>
    <num5>29</num5>
    <num6>47</num6>
    <match>25</match>
    <jackpot>8842605</jackpot>
</number>
```

PHP: This isnt using an array so only works to match 6 correct numbers

```
foreach($xml->children() as $record){
$n1 = $n1 || $record->num1 == $num1 || $record->num2 == $num1 || $record->num3 == $num1 || $record->num4 == $num1 || $record->num5 == $num1 || $record->num6 == $num1;
$n2 = $n2 || $record->num1 == $num2 || $record->num2 == $num2 || $record->num3 == $num2 || $record->num4 == $num2 || $record->num5 == $num2 || $record->num6 == $num2;
$n3 = $n3 || $record->num1 == $num3 || $record->num2 == $num3 || $record->num3 == $num3 || $record->num4 == $num3 || $record->num5 == $num3 || $record->num6 == $num3;
$n4 = $n4 || $record->num1 == $num4 || $record->num2 == $num4 || $record->num3 == $num4 || $record->num4 == $num4 || $record->num5 == $num4 || $record->num4 == $num1;
$n5 = $n5 || $record->num1 == $num5 || $record->num2 == $num5 || $record->num3 == $num5 || $record->num4 == $num5 || $record->num5 == $num5 || $record->num5 == $num1;
$n6 = $n6 || $record->num1 == $num6 || $record->num2 == $num6 || $record->num3 == $num6 || $record->num4 == $num6 || $record->num5 == $num6 || $record->num6 == $num6;
$jackpot = $record->jackpot;
$date = $record ->date;
}//end foreach

if ($n1 && $n2 && $n3 && $n4 && $n5 && $n6) 
{
  echo "<div class='col-md-6' id='date_won'>
    <h3>DATE</h3>
    <h3>".$record->date."</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6' id='amount_won'>
    <h3>AMOUNT</h3>
    <h3>&pound;".$record->jackpot."</h3>
    </div>";
}
```

Im trying to create something like http://www.mrgamez.com/lottery-calculator/

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Is there something not working correctly with the current code? Is the fact that this is XML actually relevant to the question? The only question I can see is "could I use an array to store the numbers, dates, and match and extract them from the array?" to which I think the answer is "yes", but again I'm not sure what you really mean. Could you [edit] and add a clearer question?

Comment: I've edited the question. As you say, I want to be able to use an array to get numbers and dates from the xml and match against entered numbers